# Discrepancy in the cash holdings of iShares MSCI India UCITS ETF

Tags: etf

In the [factsheet](https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/literature/fact-sheet/ndia-ishares-msci-india-ucits-etf-fund-fact-sheet-en-gb.pdf?siteEntryPassthrough=true) of [iShares MSCI India UCITS ETF USD (Acc)](https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/297617/ishares-msci-india-ucits-etf-usd-acc-fund?siteEntryPassthrough=true) (London Stock Exchange: NDIA), the "Top Holdings" section says that the "INR Cash" component is 3.57%:

[image: Top holdings of NDIA on 2021-05-31]

However, the "Geographic Breakdown" section says that "Cash and/or Derivatives" is 0.42%:

[image: Geographic breakdown of NDIA on 2021-05-31]

How can "Cash and/or Derivatives" be 0.42% when "INR Cash" is 3.57%?

Comment: I'd be more concerned with `99.61+0.42` being `100.03`.

Comment: Maybe since INR Cash is located in India, it's included in that bar